# Theme unit test error

Tags: errors, import

When i run the WordPress importer plugin with the xml(Theme unit test) i just get a lot of error, you can see the error [here](https://pastebin.com/kNGSXbQh). It's more or less everything that fails and a lot of notices.

i have tried with php7 fix but without luck as I'm running php7.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear all of those errors seem to be due to the [WordPress Importer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) itself.

You can tell because all the PHP Notices mention:

> /home/user/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/**wordpress-importer**/wordpress-importer.php

This is not your fault nor something you will be able to resolve without contributing to the plugin itself (see the final part of this answer if you are interested.)

As of this post the WordPress Importer plugin (Version 0.6.3) is in dire need of maintenance and repair. Take a look at [the plugin's support page](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-importer) and you will see a lot of other people experiencing these same issues.

In many cases the plugin may work but you are likely to experience issues and see PHP errors. I would take it with a grain of salt, meaning, backup before use (as always) and double check everything after you use it.

**There is hope however!!!**

In 2015 Ryan McCue a co-lead on the [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) project [announced he was beginning a rewrite](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/18/wordpress-importer-redux/) of the plugin dubbed *WordPress Importer Redux*. You can follow that progress (and contribute!) over at [the project's GitHub repo](https://github.com/humanmade/WordPress-Importer). Development seems active so I'd keep an eye on that one.

**Bonus:**

To really test your theme you can look into [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) and the [PHP_CodeSniffer rules (sniffs) to enforce WordPress coding conventions](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards).

Comment: if its the plugin, shouldnt the same error and notifications had happend on my local macbook aswell and not be limited to my arch setup? 

i really do appreciate the anwer, and i will have a look into these other options, i just find it weird that worked on my macbook but arch, which makes me wonder if a different setup on my arch could help :)

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't get them locally, I get them everywhere. It's all PHP errors so OS shouldn't make too much of a difference. You're sure you had `WP_DEBUG` turned on locally?

Comment: Also, what version of PHP do you run in your local environment? I'm pretty sure  these errors are generated since at least 5.6 (no time to look it up now) but that may be the factor that's making the difference.

Comment: if you are referring to the `WP_DEBUG` in from the wp-config.php, then its activated. i was running php7 yesterday, but i tired downgrading earlier today to 5.6, still didn't help. Also tried the _wordpress importer redux_ i still get the same errors. Could it be file/folder permission or my apache server setup? i have follow wordpress's own guide or recommendations, so i dont think its that..  

what i meant with os, is that osx comes with a mostly preconfigured apache server with php, some of these settings my differ from my arch and thats why it works there.

Comment: I tried reinstalling wp, wp database and installed redux, again. It now shows data inside the different posts, which is an upgrade! It's still missing media and authors/users though, any ideas? Big thanks so far!